# Extract strings inside shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a string that may contain shortcodes such as `this is a string [e]with[/e] multiple [e]shortcodes[/e]`. I want to extract strings: "with" and "shortcodes" into an array.

```
$string_with_shortcodes = "this is a string [e]with[/e] multiple [e]shortcodes[/e]";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = preg_match_all("\01\[e\](.*?)\[/e\]\01", $string_with_shortcodes, $matches);
$shortcodes_array = $matches[1];
```

Based on the example you gave,

- `$matches[0]` will contain: `Array("[e]with[/e]","[e]shortcodes[/e]")`
- `$matches[1]` will contain: `Array("with","shortcodes")`

Comment: @Liso22, not possible to omit `$matches[0]`. it contains the complete original matched pattern.